# NDSolve::ndinid: Initial condition Sign[-205.099+25. 13.^(1. -0.01 t)] is not in the range specified by the discrete variable NDSolve`s$64334

Tags: differential-equations

I have a problem trying to solve an ODE with NDSolve. the equation to solve is the following

y'(t) + Coef(t)*y(t) = Coef(t)*f(t)

where Coef(t) and f(t) are piece-wise continuous as follows:

Coef(t) = a * 10^(b1 + b2/(b3 + f(t))) if f(t) <= f_lim1, a*10^(b1' + b2'/(b3' + f(t))) if don't.

f(t) = fo*Exp(c*t) if t< t_lim1 , fc if don't.

Something to note is that if I consider a function f(t) being linear for the non-constant region, the problem is solved, but if I use the above definition the error message appears:

--> NDSolve::ndinid: Initial condition Sign[-205.099+25. 13.^(1. -0.01 t)] is not in the range specified by the discrete variable NDSolve`s$64334.

Thanks by advance for your help.

```
afunLT[T[t]]=10^(-(314317625/88090787) + 1728383341/(
 918231 (7251941891/99821070 + T[t])))
afunHT[T[t]]=10^(-(826491756/48489179) + 1615782175/(
 1430678 (-(19665592279/131685570) + T[t])))

(5000 y[t])/(
   116234853 If[
     If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 25] <= 
      205.099, 
     afunLT[If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 
       25]], afunHT[
      If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 25]]]) +
    Derivative[1][y][t] == (
  5000 (-325 + 
     If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 25]))/(
  116234853 If[
    If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 25] <= 
     205.099, 
    afunLT[If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 
      25]], afunHT[
     If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 25]]]), 
 y[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 100}
```

Comment: Could you upload code as well?

Comment: There's a variable `t` in your initial condition.  That can't be good.

Comment: Initial condition is set to y[0]==0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this? (You're code is incomplete, so I had to guess some things).

```
afunLT[T_] = 
  10^(-(314317625/88090787) + 
     1728383341/(918231 (7251941891/99821070 + T)));
afunHT[T_] = 
  10^(-(826491756/48489179) + 
     1615782175/(1430678 (-(19665592279/131685570) + T)));
NDSolve[
 Solve[{(5000 y[t])/(116234853 If[
          If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 
            25] <= 205.099, 
          afunLT[If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 
            325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 25]], 
          afunHT[If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 
            325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 25]]]) + 
      Derivative[1][y][
       t] == (5000 (-325 + 
          If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 
           25]))/(116234853 If[
         If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 
           25] <= 205.099, 
         afunLT[If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 
           325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 25]], 
         afunHT[If[25 13^(1 - t/100) >= 25, 
           325 E^(1/100 (-Log[13]) t), 25]]]), y[0] == 0}, {y'[t], 
    y[0]}
   ] /. Rule[a_, b_] :> a == PiecewiseExpand[b], y, {t, 0, 100}]
```

Does it look right?:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi @Michael E2 thanks for the help, yep it is working, could be nice from you to get a hind in why you treat the problem like this :).

Comment: I'm trying to solve 25 independent EDOs with the same form and same initial conditions, the thing is in some solutions it gives an error like this: NDSolve::nderr: Error test failure at t == 1.785085980242561`; unable to continue. And there's just 1 coefficient changing, the one multiplying Coef(t) (i.e "a" from the formulation)

Comment: @CamiloSuarez I might be able to add more later: Briefly, the error comes from the condition in your `If[]`'s (by inspection), so I converted them to `Piecewise` functions, but I had to put them all on the same side of the equals sign.  As for `nderr` on 25-ODE system, try `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`. The error comes from the default LSODA solver (IDA also produces that error), and I don't have a good grasp of what causes the error test to fail.  `"StiffnessSwitching"` sometimes succeeds in this case, so it's worth trying.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanations, Actually the Stiffness switching work for most equations just 1 of them still showing error: NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 17.947009325071043`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. Thanks a lot for the help :)